# Is there any way to automatically adjust grid column width after show/hide a column in kendo-ui grid?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the kendo-UI grid for displaying some data from my database. I have a set of predefined columns and some of them are visible/hidden by default.

Each column is set to a specific width based on the content and UI requirements and this cannot be set to auto.

There is an option for the user to show or hide columns based on their preferences. The problem is if the user hides a column, it leaves an empty space there. Is there any way to fill up the empty space( like evenly distributing the width of the hidden column to all other visible columns)

Comment: hidding a column grid children requires also to remove the column grid from the template or at least set its width to 0. any live example of the issue and method you are using ?

Comment: Just using kendoColumnMenu toolbar option to hide/show columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a work-around to fix my issue. I have written a custom function to adjust the width of each column on `ColumnHide` and `ColumnShow` events of kendo-grid.

```
function AdjustColumnWidth() {
    var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var columns = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
    var totalWidth = $('#MyGrid').width();// current width of the grid;
    var visibleColumnsWidth = 0;
    var visibleColumnsCount = 0;

    var visibleColumnsWidthAll = [70];//width for first column-this column will be shown always.
    $.each(columns, function (index) {
        if (!this.hidden) {
            if (grid.table[0].rows.length)
            {
                if (typeof grid.table[0].rows[0].cells[index]!="undefined")
                {
                    visibleColumnsWidth += grid.table[0].rows[0].cells[index].offsetWidth;
                    visibleColumnsCount += 1;
                    if (index > 0) {
                        visibleColumnsWidthAll.push(grid.table[0].rows[0].cells[index].offsetWidth);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (visibleColumnsWidth < totalWidth) {
        var diff = totalWidth - visibleColumnsWidth;
        var toAdd = diff / (visibleColumnsCount - 1);
        var tableCol = 1;
        $.each(columns, function (i) {
            if (!this.hidden && i != 0) {
                $("#MyGrid .k-grid-header-wrap").find("colgroup col").eq(tableCol).width(visibleColumnsWidthAll[tableCol] + toAdd);
                $("#MyGrid .k-grid-content").find("colgroup col").eq(tableCol).width(visibleColumnsWidthAll[tableCol] + toAdd);
                tableCol += 1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And assigned called this function on column show/hide

```
.Events(ev => ev.ColumnHide("AdjustColumnWidth").ColumnShow("AdjustColumnWidth"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this on your grid definition:

```
columnShow: function(e) {
    var newOptions = $.extend({}, grid.getOptions());
    newOptions.columns[0].width = "150px";
  }
```

check this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/ikAbU
and the columnShow event documentation here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnshow

Answer (score 1):

Simply add 2 lines in the style:

```
#grid table {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Courtesy:
[Kendo Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/auto-resize-grid-when-hiding-and-showing-columns)

Comment: Thanks Sayas, this solutions works for me